# Cannot connect to AWS RDS again

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an AWS RDS. I used to be able to connect to it via MySQL workbench, and my EC2 instance running a laravel application was also connected to it which has been working fine so far but I had an issue with my storage space and needed to download and upload some files on my ec2 instance just to free up some space.

Because I was connecting using as Filezilla I had to use the command `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu` to give ubuntu to the group so i can have access to read and write.

The problem is after running this command i noticed I can no longer connect my workbench to the RDS again. Even my laravel application can't access the RDS again.

My Laravel app throws this error

`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`

while workbench throws this

`Your connection attempt failed for user ....`

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I restarted my BD RDS